# Differences between DFSClient and FileSystem in HDFS

Tags: hdfs

What is the **difference between DFSClient Protocol and FileSystem class in Hadoop DFS** (HDFS).
Both of these classes are used for connecting a remote client to the namenode in HDFS.
So, I wanted to know the **advantages of one over the other** and which one is suitable for remote-client connection.

Answer (score 3):

[FileSystem](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) is an abstract class for file management. There are multiple implementations of the FileSystem class  like [FTPFileSystem](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/ftp/FTPFileSystem.html). Using the FileSystem API, it's easy to swap between different file systems.

[DFSClient](http://hadoop.apache.org/hdfs/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/DFSClient.html) is a specific client for HDFS and does a lot more than file management like getting the [namenode](http://hadoop.apache.org/hdfs/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/DFSClient.html#getNamenode%28%29), [getting the missing blocks count](http://hadoop.apache.org/hdfs/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/DFSClient.html#getMissingBlocksCount%28%29) etc.